# FullCalendar timezone not working

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am trying to set the timezone in this example and when time on the calendar is selected, it's clearly still in UTC despite setting the `timezone` option to 'America/New_York':

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    const fc = $('#c');
    const tz = 'America/New_York';

    const data = {
        meetings: [
            {
                title: 'Test data',
                start: 1513976400000,
                end: 1513980000000
            }
        ]
    };
    const myEvents = [];
    for (let d = 0; d < data.meetings.length; d += 1) {
        myEvents.push({
            title: 'Booked',
            start: (moment(data.meetings[d].start).tz(tz)),
            end: (moment(data.meetings[d].end).tz(tz)),
        });
    fc.fullCalendar({
        events: myEvents,
        timezone: tz,
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: 'month,agendaWeek',
            right: 'today prev,next',
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select(start, end) {
            alert(`Book a meeting for ${start.format('h:mma on dddd M/D')}?`);
        },
        selectOverlap: false,
        editable: false,
        eventOverlap: false,
    });

});
```

Can anyone confirm that this is a bug or user error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change moment default timezone to required timezone (below is the working 
 example change timezone and observe event on calendar).

```js
$(function () {
    var timeZone = 'America/New_York';
    var now = moment().add(moment.tz(timeZone).utcOffset(), "m");
    moment.tz.setDefault(timeZone);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     header: {
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
             events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json',
             defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
             timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
      
            editable: true,
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/lib/rrule.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Nitin, thanks for the suggestion, but that's not changing anything for fullcalendar - could you provide a working example of this fix?

Comment: @StephenGheysens: see I have provided the working example.